# Unable to access new database fields after rebuilding RiaService

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, ria

I have a solution that uses a RiaService project.  I have been using it successfully for quite some time.  On my last database change though, I came across a problem where any new fields are giving an error when I access them in my Silverlight project.

After a load operation I set my property to the first record returned:

```
Rights = loadOp.Entities.First();
```

At this point I am able to access all the old fields:

```
int _id = Rights.Id
string _name = Rights.Name
```

But when I try to access a newly added database field:

```
string _description = Right.Description
```

I get the following error:

- RIAServices.Web.Models.Rights' does not contain a definition for
  'Description' and no extension method 'Description' accepting a first
  argument of type 'RIAServices.Web.Models.Rights' could be
  found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't get an error on the build, so it is seeing the correct metadata and recognizing that the DESCRIPTION field is valid.  And it builds the RiaService just fine with the DESCRIPTION in the metadata.  So I am at a loss as to why this happening.  I have done this same thing hundreds of times as I build a project adding new tables and fields and I have never seen this before.

Comment: It is about a dozen different field names.  It just started a couple days ago so all 12 new fields are not being seen while the old fields still all work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a backup from about 3 weeks ago that was working correctly and manually updated the code up to the present.  That seems to have done the trick, but without determining the actual cause of the problem.